# Why is there a strange white border on Gnome Terminal?

Tags: 13.04, gnome-terminal

I am getting a strange white border for the Gnome terminal in Ubuntu 13.04. Any suggestions as to how to remove it?

Here's a screeshot:

[image]

Comment: Anything strange?

Comment: Looks like a window decoration to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the shadow color with white code. its gives you no problem.

If you dont want that effect then you do it from CCSM.

open your terminal and type as `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

then from your unity dash type as compiz and you can select it from the resulted menu.Now open that application then at Effects section  uncheck the window decoration option.[image]